# lto1: fatal error generated with LTO version 11.0 instead of the expected 11.2

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc, versions

I'm trying to install many packages (phagorn, phytools...) on recently updated RStudio and Ubuntu 22. It seems that some dependencies are needed, as igraph but when trying to install it, I got the error:

lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream in file ‘vendor/arpack/dgetv0.o’ generated with LTO version 11.0 instead of the expected 11.2
compilation terminated.

lto-wrapper: fatal error: g++ returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: igraph.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

Please, any suggestions on how to solve this ??

Comment: I run into the same error but have not found any solutions yet.  If I do, I'll report back!

Comment: You probably updated your compiler, but still have some object files (build output) sitting around that are not compatible with the new compiler. Try cleaning your build output, then rebuild.

Comment: This occurred too in a kernel compiling process, particularly tools/build/feature, in feature_check related directive, with update-alternative provides gcc-12/g++-12 for gcc/g++ groups and gcc-11/g++-11 present in my system.

Comment: I had the same issue and Thomas' comment resolved the issue.